# como poner un texto sobre un carrusel en bootstrap 5.2

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-carousel

me gustaria saber como es la forma correcta de poner un texto sobre un carrusel de 3 imagenes, me gustaria que las 3 imagenes tengan el mismo contenido de texto, por el momento tengo asi el codigo
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

como pueden ver pego el mismo codigo bajo cada imagen del carrusel me funciona pero me gustaria ahorrar codigo. ya intente pegandolo encima de los carousel-item y no funciona. o habria que sobreponer un div sobre el carrusel, intente esto tambien pero no me salio bien :C

Comment: por lo que entendí es que necesitas ahorrar codigo, pero que muestra las siguentes imagenes no?

Comment: Por favor agrega el código como texto. Te invito a leer [ask] y [example]